# Using Watin how do I set the text value for this element?

Tags: html, watin

I have an unusual calendar control in my HTML page that I can not seem to set the date value for.  The HTML is:

```
<div class="reqFormLabel" style="margin-bottom: -3px;">
    Text - First Night 
<span id="ctlAvailabilitySearch_valStartDate" style="color: red; visibility: hidden;" controltovalidate="ctlAvailabilitySearch_txtStartDate" errormessage="First Night is required." initialvalue="" isvalid="true">
    Text - *
Text - Empty Text Node
<input name="ctlAvailabilitySearch$txtStartDate" id="ctlAvailabilitySearch_txtStartDate" style="display: none;" value="03/05/2013"/>
Text - Empty Text Node
<dropdown tabIndex="0" class="dp" id="startDP" style="margin-right: 8px;" formElChildIndex="0"/>
```

If execute this code:

```
var ieElement = ieFrame.Element(Find.ById("ctlAvailabilitySearch_txtStartDate"));
var value = ieElement.GetAttributeValue("value");
```

value equals the date of "03/05/2013"

But if I execute this:

```
ieElement.SetAttributeValue("value", "03/09/2013");
```

nothing happens.

I've tried accessing every possible element combination I can think of to set this date, but nothing is working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 0 down vote
 

Do you have a link to the page for testing... any reference to the code documentation... etc.

Comment: In some more complicated controls, eg: calendar, you'll need to fire a JavaScript event to get the page to update.  The Chrome F12 tools are helpful for figuring out which events are wired to which elements.